# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I am trying to simply print the number of rows .xlsx file

Tags: apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror

When I am trying to run my XLUtil class to count the number of rows in the XLSX file I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
    at testXLSReadWrite.XLUtils.getRowCount(XLUtils.java:23)
    at testXLSReadWrite.SimpleReadClass.main(SimpleReadClass.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

the classes I am using are here under

```
package testXLSReadWrite;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SimpleReadClass {
    static XLUtils xl = new XLUtils();
    public static void main(String [] ss) throws IOException {
        
        int row = xl.getRowCount("C:\\Users\\jq2870\\eclipse-workspace\\TestJava Project\\configuration\\UserLoginData.xlsx", "Sheet1");
    
        System.out.print(row);
    }

}
```

And XLUtils class is

```
public class XLUtils {
public static FileInputStream fi;
public static FileOutputStream fo;
public static XSSFWorkbook wb;
public static XSSFSheet ws;
public static XSSFRow row;
public static XSSFCell cell;

public static int getRowCount(String xlfile,String xlsheet) throws IOException{
fi = new FileInputStream(xlfile);
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
ws = wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
int rowcount = ws.getLastRowNum();
wb.close();
fi.close();
return rowcount;
}
public static int getCellCount(String xlfile, String xlsheet,int rownum) throws IOException {
fi = new FileInputStream(xlfile);
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
ws = wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
row = ws.getRow(rownum);
int cellcount = row.getLastCellNum();
wb.close();
fi.close();
return cellcount;
}

public static String getCellData(String xlfile, String xlsheet,int rownum, int colnum) throws IOException
{
    fi = new FileInputStream(xlfile);
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
    ws = wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
    row = ws.getRow(rownum);
    cell = row.getCell(colnum);
    String data;
    try{
        DataFormatter formatter =  new DataFormatter();
        String cellData = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        return cellData;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        data = "";
    }
    wb.close();
    fi.close();
    return data;
}

public  static void setCellData(String xlfile, String xlsheet,int rownum, int colnum, String data) throws IOException {
    fi = new FileInputStream(xlfile);
    wb =  new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
    ws = wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
    row = ws.getRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(colnum);
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    fo = new FileOutputStream(xlfile);
    wb.write(fo);
    wb.close();
    fi.close();
    fo.close();
    
}

}
```

Please can someone tell me why this is happening, every time it's saying that the XSSFWorkbook.class is not found.
I am using Eclipse IDE Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
and Java version Java SE 1.8.0 (JDK 14.0.1)

XL file is having Single row with Username and Password

Comment: How did you add all the jars and dependencies of Apache POI to your project?

Comment: I am adding it manually, by going in to the build path, not using any xml file.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add all the dependencies. This is the risk of doing it yourself. What happens when you add all the dependencies?

Comment: I changed my project to maven and deleted the manually added dependencies and it worked, thanks a-lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)